# Simple setup for basic Angular 2 app

Tags: angular

I took a coding test for a job and opted to try and do the test in Angular 2, though my experience with it is pretty minimal.  I downloaded the package from Google but was as interested in the extra testing items, etc. that they put in there.  Is there a good example of creating a pretty minimalist 'Hello World' for Angular 2.  Are there some suggestions for creating a simple package and can be executed and ran for a similar kind of test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set thing up fast, can use angular-cli to bootstrap your project (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

There are a couple of seed project you can use too. e.g. https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed

Answer (score 0):

[Here in this tutorial](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2017/05/learn-angular2-step-by-step.html), you can see a very basic setup for angular 2 application has been done with a "Hello world" application.

In this tutorial, Also provided [angular 2 setup files](https://github.com/dotnetawesome/AngularJS2Seed) and described each and every file very well which makes you understand how we can create a very basic angular 2 application.